# Formatting number of Matplotlib ticks (thousands). TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, kivy, typeerror

I am building an app which shows the sales achieved by a salesman on different time periods. There are 4 checkboxes with different time periods (Day, Week, Month, Year). Upon clicking on any period, a matplotlib time-line graph will be shown.

My struggle comes as I am trying to format the y-ticks as thousands. I am using the `format(value, ',')` command. However I keep getting the `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` . Upon research I've found the suggestion is to explicitly state the value as int. I've tried this in multiple ways but have no success. For example, If I add an int() to convert from string to int: `int(format(divider * 1, ','))` I get the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '150,000'`

Code for minimal reproducible example is the following:

**Python code:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
matplotlib.use("module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy")
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg


class LabelButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    pass



class MainMenuWindow(Screen):
    pass



class DashboardWindow(Screen):
    # Valores Iniciales
    """ PENDIENTE: HACER QUE LOS VALORES INICIALES VARÍEN EN FUNCIÓN DEL VENDEDOR Y SUS NÚMEROS """
    meta_mensual = 300000
    venta_diaria_ = 2500
    venta_semanal_ = 50000
    venta_mensual_ = 230000
    venta_anual_ = 2500000
    menu = None
    number_items_mdlist = 0
    minutes_items_mdlist = 0
    duracion_actividades_list = []
    picture_filepath_list = []
    image_status_list = []
    periodo_selec = ''

    # Ventas
    def diario_label_press(self, value):
        if not self.ids.periodo_diario_.active:
            self.ids.periodo_diario_.active = True
        else:
            self.ids.periodo_diario_.active = False

    def semanal_label_press(self, value):
        if not self.ids.periodo_semanal_.active:
            self.ids.periodo_semanal_.active = True
        else:
            self.ids.periodo_semanal_.active = False

    def mensual_label_press(self, value):
        if not self.ids.periodo_mensual_.active:
            self.ids.periodo_mensual_.active = True
        else:
            self.ids.periodo_mensual_.active = False

    def anual_label_press(self, value):
        if not self.ids.periodo_anual_.active:
            self.ids.periodo_anual_.active = True
        else:
            self.ids.periodo_anual_.active = False

    def switch_checkbox(self):
        if self.ids.periodo_diario_.active:
            # Meta de Ventas
            meta_diaria = int(self.meta_mensual) / 30
            meta_diaria_format = '{:,}'.format(meta_diaria)
            self.ids.meta_label.text = "$ " + str(meta_diaria_format) + "0"
            # Monto de Venta
            venta = int(self.venta_diaria_)
            venta = '{:,}'.format(venta)
            self.ids.monto_venta.text = "$ " + str(venta) + ".00"
            # Porcentaje de Meta
            porcentaje = float(self.venta_diaria_ / meta_diaria)
            porcentaje_format = "{0:.1%}".format(porcentaje)
            self.ids.porcentaje_meta.text = str(porcentaje_format)
            self.periodo_selec = 'Diario'

        elif self.ids.periodo_semanal_.active:
            # Meta de Ventas
            meta_semanal = int(self.meta_mensual) / 4
            meta_semanal_format = '{:,}'.format(meta_semanal)
            self.ids.meta_label.text = "$ " + str(meta_semanal_format) + "0"
            # Monto de Venta
            venta = int(self.venta_semanal_)
            venta = '{:,}'.format(venta)
            self.ids.monto_venta.text = "$ " + str(venta) + ".00"
            # Porcentaje de Meta
            porcentaje = float(self.venta_semanal_ / meta_semanal)
            porcentaje_format = "{0:.1%}".format(porcentaje)
            self.ids.porcentaje_meta.text = str(porcentaje_format)
            self.periodo_selec = 'Semanal'

        elif self.ids.periodo_mensual_.active:
            # Meta de Ventas
            meta_mensual = int(self.meta_mensual) * 1
            meta_mensual_format = '{:,}'.format(self.meta_mensual)
            self.ids.meta_label.text = "$ " + str(meta_mensual_format) + ".00"
            # Monto de Venta
            venta = int(self.venta_mensual_)
            venta = '{:,}'.format(venta)
            self.ids.monto_venta.text = "$ " + str(venta) + ".00"
            # Porcentaje de Meta
            porcentaje = float(self.venta_mensual_ / self.meta_mensual)
            porcentaje_format = "{0:.1%}".format(porcentaje)
            self.ids.porcentaje_meta.text = str(porcentaje_format)
            self.periodo_selec = 'Mensual'

        elif self.ids.periodo_anual_.active:
            # Meta de Ventas
            meta_anual = int(self.meta_mensual) * 12
            meta_anual_format = '{:,}'.format(meta_anual)
            self.ids.meta_label.text = "$ " + str(meta_anual_format) + ".00"
            # Monto de Venta
            venta = int(self.venta_anual_)
            venta = '{:,}'.format(venta)
            self.ids.monto_venta.text = "$ " + str(venta) + ".00"
            # Porcentaje de Meta
            porcentaje = float(self.venta_anual_ / meta_anual)
            porcentaje_format = "{0:.1%}".format(porcentaje)
            self.ids.porcentaje_meta.text = str(porcentaje_format)
            self.periodo_selec = 'Anual'

        elif not self.ids.periodo_diario_.active and not self.ids.periodo_semanal_.active and \
                not self.ids.periodo_mensual_.active and not self.ids.periodo_anual_.active:
            # Meta de Ventas
            self.ids.meta_label.text = "Seleccione una opción"
            self.ids.monto_venta.text = "$ 0.00"
            self.ids.porcentaje_meta.text = "0.00 %"

        self.actualizar_timeline_ventas(self.periodo_selec)

    def actualizar_timeline_ventas(self, selec):
        now = datetime.now()

        dash = MDApp.get_running_app().root.get_screen('dash')
        plt.clf()
        plt.style.use('seaborn')

        mes = ''
        if now.month == 1:
            mes = 'Enero'
        elif now.month == 2:
            mes = 'Febrero'
        elif now.month == 3:
            mes = 'Marzo'
        elif now.month == 4:
            mes = 'Abril'
        elif now.month == 5:
            mes = 'Mayo'
        elif now.month == 6:
            mes = 'Junio'
        elif now.month == 7:
            mes = 'Julio'
        elif now.month == 8:
            mes = 'Agosto'
        elif now.month == 9:
            mes = 'Septiembre'
        elif now.month == 10:
            mes = 'Octubre'
        elif now.month == 11:
            mes = 'Noviembre'
        elif now.month == 12:
            mes = 'Diciembre'

        # Línea de tiempo del día
        if self.ids.periodo_diario_.active:
            dia_semana = ''
            if now.weekday() == 0:
                dia_semana = 'Lunes'
            elif now.weekday() == 1:
                dia_semana = 'Martes'
            elif now.weekday() == 2:
                dia_semana = 'Miércoles'
            elif now.weekday() == 3:
                dia_semana = 'Jueves'
            elif now.weekday() == 4:
                dia_semana = 'Viernes'
            elif now.weekday() == 5:
                dia_semana = 'Sábado'
            elif now.weekday() == 6:
                dia_semana = 'Domingo'

            dash.ids.momento_seleccionado.text = f'Hoy, {dia_semana.lower()}, {now.day} de {mes.lower()} del {now.year}'
            dash.ids.timeline_container.clear_widgets()

            hora = ['9:00 a.m.', '10:00 a.m.', '11:00 a.m.', '12:00 p.m.', '1:00 p.m.', '2:00 p.m.', '3:00 p.m.',
                    '4:00 p.m.', '5:00 p.m.', '6:00 p.m.']
            venta = [0, 1500, 10000, 17000, 2600, 0, 0, 2710, 7500, 0]

            divider = max(venta) / 4
            plt.yticks([0, divider * 1, divider * 2, divider * 3, divider * 4])

            plt.plot(hora, venta, color='blue', marker='D')
            plt.xticks(['9:00 a.m.', '12:00 p.m.', '3:00 p.m.', '6:00 p.m.'])
            plt.grid(True)
            dash.ids.timeline_container.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(figure=plt.gcf(), size_hint=(0.95, 0.95),
                                                                       pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}))

        # Línea de tiempo Semanal
        elif self.ids.periodo_semanal_.active:
            dash.ids.momento_seleccionado.text = f'Semana {datetime.date(now).isocalendar()[1]} del {now.year}'
            dash.ids.timeline_container.clear_widgets()

            dia = ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom']
            venta = [10000, 12000, 22000, 17000, 26000, 5000, 0]

            divider = max(venta) / 4
            plt.yticks([0, divider * 1, divider * 2, divider * 3, divider * 4])

            plt.plot(dia, venta, color='yellow', marker='o')
            plt.grid(True)
            dash.ids.timeline_container.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(figure=plt.gcf(), size_hint=(0.95, 0.95),
                                                                       pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}))

        # Línea de tiempo mensual
        elif self.ids.periodo_mensual_.active:

            dash.ids.momento_seleccionado.text = f'{mes} {now.year}'
            dash.ids.timeline_container.clear_widgets()

            now = datetime.now()
            curr_month = now.now().month
            if int(curr_month) == 1 or int(curr_month) == 3 or int(curr_month) == 5 or int(curr_month) == 7 \
                    or int(curr_month) == 8 or int(curr_month) == 10 or int(curr_month) == 12:
                number_days = 31
            elif int(curr_month) == 4 or int(curr_month) == 6 or int(curr_month) == 9 or int(curr_month) == 11:
                number_days = 30
            else:
                number_days = 28

            import random
            dia = []
            venta = []
            day = 1
            for i in range(number_days):
                dia.append(day)
                venta.append(random.randrange(150000, 750000))
                day += 1

            divider = max(venta) / 4
            plt.yticks([0, divider * 1, divider * 2, divider * 3, divider * 4])
            plt.plot(dia, venta, color='red', marker='s')
            plt.grid(True)
            dash.ids.timeline_container.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(figure=plt.gcf(), size_hint=(0.95, 0.95),
                                                                       pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}))
        # Línea de tiempo Anual
        elif self.ids.periodo_anual_.active:
            dash.ids.momento_seleccionado.text = str(now.year)
            dash.ids.timeline_container.clear_widgets()

            mes = ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
            venta = [100000, 120000, 130000, 170000, 260000, 220000, 243000, 271000, 274000, 320000, 430000, 600000]

            divider = int(max(venta) / 4)
            plt.yticks([int(0), format(divider * 1, ','), format(divider * 2, ','), format(divider * 3, ','),
                        format(divider * 4, ',')])

            plt.plot(mes, venta, color='green', marker='^')
            plt.grid(True)
            dash.ids.timeline_container.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(figure=plt.gcf(), size_hint=(0.95, 0.95),
                                                                       pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}))

        else:
            dash.ids.momento_seleccionado.text = 'Líneas de tiempo'
            dash.ids.timeline_container.clear_widgets()
            dash.ids.timeline_container.add_widget(self.ids.label_timeline_vacio)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Linegraph(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Linegraph().run()
```

**KV Code:**

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: screen_manager

    DashboardWindow:
        id: dash
        name: 'dash'

<DashboardWindow>:
    id: dash
    name:'dash'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        valign: 'middle'
        padding: '10dp'

        MDLabel:
            text: "Nombre del Vendedor"
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 12.75**4
            valign: 'middle'
            bold: True
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: '5dp'
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            MDLabel:
                text: "Meta de venta:"
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14.25**4
            MDLabel:
                id: meta_label
                text: 'Seleccione una opcion'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14.25**4
                bold: True

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: '5dp'
            size_hint_y: 0.20
            MDCheckbox:
                group: 'periodo_venta'
                id: periodo_diario_
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(50), dp(50)
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "center_y":0.5}
                on_active:
                    root.switch_checkbox()
            LabelButton:
                text: 'Diario'
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                text_size: self.size
                on_release: root.diario_label_press(root.ids.periodo_diario_.active)

            MDCheckbox:
                group: 'periodo_venta'
                id: periodo_semanal_
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(50), dp(50)
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "center_y":0.5}
                on_active:
                    root.switch_checkbox()
            LabelButton:
                text: 'Semanal'
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                text_size: self.size
                on_release: root.semanal_label_press(root.ids.periodo_semanal_.active)

            MDCheckbox:
                group: 'periodo_venta'
                id: periodo_mensual_
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(50), dp(50)
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "center_y":0.5}
                on_active:
                    root.switch_checkbox()
            LabelButton:
                text: 'Mensual'
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                text_size: self.size
                on_release: root.mensual_label_press(root.ids.periodo_mensual_.active)

            MDCheckbox:
                group: 'periodo_venta'
                id: periodo_anual_
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(50), dp(50)
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "center_y":0.5}
                on_active:
                    root.switch_checkbox()
            LabelButton:
                text: 'Anual'
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                text_size: self.size
                on_release: root.anual_label_press(root.ids.periodo_anual_.active)

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            padding: 0, '10dp', 0, 0
            spacing: '20dp'
            size_hint: 1, 0.25
            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: '10dp'
                size_hint: 0.4, 1
                radius: [16, ]
                md_bg_color: [1, 1, 1, 0.85]
                MDLabel:
                    id: monto_venta
                    text: "$ 0.00"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    font_style: 'H1'
                    halign: 'center'
                    font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Monto Vendido"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    font_style: 'Subtitle2'
                    halign: 'center'

            MDCard:
                size_hint: 0.4, 1
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: '10dp'
                radius: [16, ]
                md_bg_color: [1, 1, 1, 0.85]
                MDLabel:
                    id: porcentaje_meta
                    text: '0.00 %'
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    font_style: 'H1'
                    halign: 'center'
                    font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                MDLabel:
                    text: "% de meta alcanzado"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    font_style: 'Subtitle2'
                    halign: 'center'

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: '10dp'
            # padding: "10dp", 0,"10dp", "10dp"
            size_hint_y: 0.45
            MDCard:
                size_hint: 1, 0.9
                orientation: 'vertical'
                radius: [16, ]

                MDBoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.175
                    radius: [16, 16, 0, 0]
                    md_bg_color: 0.114, 0.212, 0.235, 1
                    MDLabel:
                        id: momento_seleccionado
                        text: 'Lineas de tiempo'
                        halign: 'center'
                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                MDSeparator:
                    height: "2dp"
                    color: 0.95, 0.81, 0.25, 1
                MDBoxLayout:
                    id: timeline_container
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    radius: [0, 0, 16, 16]
                    MDLabel:
                        id: label_timeline_vacio
                        text: 'Seleccionar temporalidad para visualizar ventas del periodo'
                        halign: 'center'
```

As you can see, the only checkbox which attempts to do the thousand formatting is for 'Year'. Therefore, this will be the only button which will result in the app crashing. Note that the reason I used the divider variable is to get 5 evenly distributed ticks. Any suggestions on how I can achieve the formatting of the ticks correctly?

As a second part of the question, I will greatly appreciate suggestions on how to add popup labels which are shown when clicking on different points of the graphs. I have found such but only on the Folium package for maps. Are there any similar solutions for matplotlib?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you problem is with the line:

```
        plt.yticks([int(0), format(divider * 1, ','), format(divider * 2, ','), format(divider * 3, ','), format(divider * 4, ',')])
```

The `yticks()` method takes zero, one, or two arguments. If you provide just one argument, as the above line does, then it must be an array of numbers, not strings. If you want to specify the actual labels, then you must provide two arguments - the list of numbers and another list of strings. So, I believe the above line should be:

```
plt.yticks([0, divider * 1, divider * 2, divider * 3, divider * 4], ['0', format(divider * 1, ','), format(divider * 2, ','), format(divider * 3, ','), format(divider * 4, ',')])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response John. You were right. Your solution worked exactly as expected. 

Do you have any comments or suggestions for my second part of the question? On the popup labels? Is there a module which does the job in matplotlib as there is in Folium? Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: My best guess for Popup Labels would be to extend `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` and implement an `on_touch_down()` method that does the Popup stuff. Nothing that I know of as far as ready to use packages.